# Set element below another element and delete current place element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I'll try my best to explain and i'd appreciate your help and your suggestions. I've section where have few input divs and these input divs have options div under input divs for to delete that div or send above to upper div and, Third option send below. Delete one is working but above one and below one is difficult. I wanna send div  below to another div. and then delete that div from its actual place. Delete one is working, but first i wanna add then delete here is code which i'm using.

```js
  const downwordButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.downword-button');

  if(downwordButtons){

  const downwordButtonsArr = Array.from(downwordButtons);

  downwordButtonsArr.forEach(button => {
      button.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');

      button.addEventListener('click', () => {

          //Selecting div options div is where buttons are stored
          const optionsDiv = button.parentElement;
          // This is div which i selected with click of that button
          const editDiv = optionsDiv.previousSibling;

          // This is complicated part where i wanna select below element
          const downwordDiv= editDiv.nextSibling;

          downwordDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', editDiv);
          downwordDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', optionsDiv);

          // it'll delete both option div and input div after finish
          optionsDiv.parentElement.removeChild(optionsDiv);
          editDiv.parentElement.removeChild(editDiv);


          // Event listener end
      });


      // Foreach end
  });

  // If end
  }
```

HTML

```html
  <div>
      <label for="user_login">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
  </div>
      <div class="Admin_edit">
          <button class="button_delete"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_downword'><ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_upword'><ion-icon name="arrow-up-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

      </div>
      <div>
          <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
          <div class="forget">
              <a class='forgetButton' href='#'>Forgot Password ?</a>
          </div>
      </div>
       <div class="Admin_edit">
          <button class="button_delete"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_downword'><ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_upword'><ion-icon name="arrow-up-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

      </div>
```

Comment: If you go to the previous and next sibling without doing anything in between you will end back where you started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution of this problem i added edit buttons div in input div and instead of nextSibling and previousSibling i used parent node and for to convert html element to js string i used (outerHtml) This is for to select current one with button. For change position with down one i used previous element var with parent node and after that i added nextElementSibling and this is making you angry, i was also last night but it's working now, So check code, it'd help you to understand.

JS

```js
const downwordButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.downword-button');

  if(downwordButtons){

  const downwordButtonsArr = Array.from(downwordButtons);

  downwordButtonsArr.forEach(button => {
      button.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false');

      button.addEventListener('click', () => {

          // Now just have to select this 
          const CurDiv = button.parentElement.parentNode;
          
          // Convert into js string html
          const html = `${CurDiv.outerHTML}`;

          //Here Select below element  
          const downwordDiv = CurDiv.nextElementSibling;

          downwordDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);

          // it'll delete both option div and input div after finish
          optionsDiv.parentElement.removeChild(optionsDiv);
          
          // Finally remove old div (CurDiv)
          CurDiv.parentElement.removeChild(CurDiv);


          // Event listener end
      });


      // Foreach end
  });

  // If end
  }
```

HTML

```html
 <div>
      <label for="user_login">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
          <div class="Admin_edit">
          <button class="button_delete"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_downword'><ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_upword'><ion-icon name="arrow-up-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

      </div>
      
  </div>
  
      <div>
          <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
          <div class="forget">
              <a class='forgetButton' href='#'>Forgot Password ?</a>
          </div>
           <div class="Admin_edit">
          <button class="button_delete"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_downword'><ion-icon name="arrow-down-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
          <button class='button_upword'><ion-icon name="arrow-up-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

      </div> 
      </div>
```